# Create graph based on selection of input and output

Tags: r, plot, shiny, render, selectinput

New to shiny. I am trying to create a plot based on chosen x and y values. Basically, whatever the user selects for the select1 and select2 selectInput function will graph it accordingly. My original data has many columns, not just two. When I try to graph very specific things, my code works great, but when I try to graph what the user "selects" it does not work.

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data0 <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 100, sd = 5)
data1 <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 50, sd = 10)
data2 <- data.frame(data0, data1)


attach(data2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  selectInput(inputId = "select1",
              label = "select the x-axis",
              choices = c(" ", "data0", "data1")
  ),
  
  selectInput(inputId = "select2",
              label = "select the y-axis",
              choices = c(" ", "data0", "data1")
  ),
  
  
  submitButton(text = "Apply Changes", icon = NULL, width = NULL),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "myplot")
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    
    
    data2 %>%
      ggplot(aes(input$select1 ~ input$select2))+
      geom_point(alpha = 0.8)
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You omitted the curly braces in renderPlot. I.e. `renderPlot({ ....  })` Also delete the commas.

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it tomorrow, and let you know how it goes. If that's all that's wrong though, then I'm not going to be upset over not figuring it out. I just need some more experience to remember basic things like that.

Comment: @RicVillalba

I fixed it. I updated my code, because I had some improper calls in there. Definitely needed your fix, but also the key was to change my ggplot to ggplot(aes(x = get(paste(input$select1)), y = get(paste(input$select2)).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add ggplot(aes(x = get(paste(input$select1)), y = get(paste(input$select2)) to make the input selects work.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(readr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    
    data0 <- read_csv("DeltaX_Soil_Properties_Fall2020_Spring2021_Fall2021.csv")
    data1 <- data0[!(data0$time_marker_sampled == "-9999"),]
    attach(data1)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
    
      selectInput(inputId = "select1",
                  label = "select the x-axis",
                  choices = c(" ", "elevation_navd88", "sediment_accretion", "days_between_sampling_and_deployment", "normalized_accretion", "soil_bulk_density", "soil_organic_matter_content", "soil_organic_carbon", "soil_organic_carbon_density")
      ),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "select2",
                  label = "select the y-axis",
                  choices = c(" ", "elevation_navd88", "sediment_accretion", "days_between_sampling_and_deployment", "normalized_accretion", "soil_bulk_density", "soil_organic_matter_content", "soil_organic_carbon", "soil_organic_carbon_density")
      ),
      
      
      submitButton(text = "Apply Changes", icon = NULL, width = NULL),
      
       plotOutput(outputId = "myplot")
      
    )
    
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      
      
      output$myplot <- renderPlot({
        
    
          data1 %>%
          ggplot(aes(x = get(paste(input$select1)), y = get(paste(input$select2)), col = hydrogeomorphic_zone))+
          geom_point(alpha = 0.8)
            
        })
      
    }
    
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable as x or y, you can alternatively use aes_() instead of aes().

This would then result in:

```
ggplot(aes_(x = input$select1, y = input$select2))
```

Beware, that you need to add a tilde if you want to use a normal column name with aes_(), e.g.:

```
ggplot(aes_(x = ~elevation_navd88, y = input$select2))
```

Comment: That's good to know. I have been busy, so I will test it out later. I wanted to clean it up, because the x and y axis labels were listing "input$select1"